# Only variables should be passed by reference Magento 1

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm getting this error that only leads to the file path; no specific line. The file that it leads to is a plugin. The plugin still works but I'm getting the error in my logs on run-time.

Comment: Please don't put links in the question. Instead, embed the image into it by clicking the image button.

Comment: It won't let me because I'm new.